# Xcode merge two branch Git

Tags: xcode, git, merge-conflict-resolution

I have two branch and they are called as NewFeature1 and subFun100. subFun100 is a branch created from previous commit in NewFeature1. Now, I have fixed code in subFun100 and I want to merge back into NewFeature1 branch. But, I have conflict like this. I just want to take both codes and how shall I do? Merge button is hidden and I can't click. Is there any step I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Merging Two Branches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/MergingTwoBranches/MergingTwoBranches.html) from developer apple.

> 3 . Resolve differences by using the left and right buttons to specify which file’s contents to use.
>
> 4 . After resolving all differences and conflicts, click Merge.

[image]

Use these 4 buttons. (red circle)

[How To Use Git Source Control with Xcode in iOS 7](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Currently, I don't know how to solve conflict.

Comment: I have selected to choose both. Problem is i can't click Merge. It look like i will need to do in working copy as described by Gabriele Petronella.

Comment: I can see total 3 differences. You've chosen `both` to 1 conflict. Still there are 2 conflicts pending. Select the other 2 conflict and choose an option. `Merge` button will be enabled.

Comment: @KhantThuLinn choose left for the other two conflicts. copy `subFun100` method form right side and paste it in the left side. (below `subFunctionInNewFeature` method)

Comment: Thanks. now Merge is enabled. I have done as you describe and it get the best merging like this. http://tinypic.com/r/fyk12d/8 . So, it means I will need to write file manually. xCode can't include both function

Comment: Yes, In this case Xcode can't. The image [on url] is not right. please copy the whole `-(void)subFun100{...}` method

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve each conflict, choosing either left, right or both.
Only then you can complete the merge.

Comment: Yes. I try to choose both. Problem is I can't click Merge. Is there additional step should I need to do?

Comment: You have two more conflicts to go, marked with a `?` sign.

Comment: Yes. How shall I do that two ? . I want to take both 2 function (subFunctionInNewFeature, subFun100) and call them in  newfeature1.

Comment: That's beyond a normal merge, since you're significantly changing the structure. You will have to manually edit the file in the working copy: `To reconcile any differences not handled by the four button choices, you can edit the file in the working copy.` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/MergingTwoBranches/MergingTwoBranches.html